# MovieClip within MovieClips frame change on hitTest

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, game-engine, movieclip, hittest

I have a car that drives around a map named "car" that's within a movieclip named "map".
I have a character named "player" who has 2 frames, "norm" which contains another movieclip named "playerNorm" which is the normal state of the character. In "dead", the character is dead. I want it so that when "player" collides with "car", "player" will show it's "dead" state.

```
stop();
onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    if (_root.playerNorm.hitTest(_root.car))
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("dead");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not clear what your problem is, I assume it to be '*The above snippet is not working*' the way you want. If so, then you need to replace :

```
this.gotoAndStop("dead");
```

with

```
_root.playerNorm.gotoAndStop("dead");
```